# Derivative of vector expression

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I am reading about the method of weighted least squares in regression, and the following formula comes up:

$S_w=(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X\beta})^TV^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X\beta})$,

where $V$ is the variance-covariance matrix, $\beta$ is a vector of parameters to be estimated, and $X$ are the covariate matrix.

I wonder how one gets to the result:

$\frac{\partial S_w}{\partial \mathbf{\beta}}=-2\mathbf{X}^TV^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X\beta})$.

Comment: Looks as if some dependence on $ /beta$ is not showing up, what is $/mu$?

Comment: @GCab fixed, thanks

Comment: Good, but at least show how you did it.

Comment: @GCab: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I am asking how one does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that you edit your post, it is clear.
Just you have to consider that $S_{\,w}$ is a scalar value, so that:
$$
S_{\,w}  = \left( {{\bf y} - {\bf X}\,\beta } \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \;{\bf V}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} \;\left( {{\bf y} - {\bf X}\beta } \right) = S_{\,w} ^{\,{\bf T}}  = \left( {{\bf y} - {\bf X}\,\beta } \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \;\left( {{\bf V}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} } \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \;\left( {{\bf y} - {\bf X}\beta } \right)
$$
and: ${\bf V}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}}  = \left( {{\bf V}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} } \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad {\bf V}\;{\rm symmetric}$

also ${{\partial \,S_{\,w} } \over {\partial \,\beta }}$ is a scalar value, and thus:
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{\partial \,S_{\,w} } \over {\partial \,\beta }} = \left( {{{\partial \,S_{\,w} } \over {\partial \,\beta }}} \right)^{\,{\bf T}}  = \left( { - {\bf X}} \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \;{\bf V}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} \;\left( {{\bf y} - {\bf X}\beta } \right) + \left( {{\bf y} - {\bf X}\,\beta } \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \;{\bf V}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} \;\left( { - {\bf X}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{\bf y} - {\bf X}\beta } \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \;\left( {{\bf V}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} } \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \;\left( { - {\bf X}} \right) + \left( { - {\bf X}} \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \;\left( {{\bf V}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} } \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \;\left( {{\bf y} - {\bf X}\,\beta } \right) =   \cr 
  &  =  - 2\;{\bf X}^{\,{\bf T}} \;{\bf V}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} \;\left( {{\bf y} - {\bf X}\,\beta } \right) =  - 2\left( {{\bf y} - {\bf X}\beta } \right)^{\,{\bf T}} \;{\bf V}^{\, - \,{\bf 1}} \;{\bf X} \cr} 
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Can i ask why you transposed the expression first? I assume you wanted to show the symmetry, but why?

Comment: As I told , since $S_{\,w} $ is a scalar quantity, then when it is a result of a matrix-vector identity, it shall be that transposing that identity you shall get the same result.

Comment: More precisely, the dot product of two (real) vectors is defined as $$
{\bf \vec x}_{\,h}  \circ {\bf \vec y}_{\,h}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,h} {x_{\,j} \,y_{\,j} }  = \overline {{\bf x}_{\,h} } \,{\bf y}_{\,h}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j\, \le \,h} {y_{\,j} \,x_{\,j} }  = \overline {{\bf y}_{\,h} } \,{\bf x}_{\,h}  = \overline {\left( {{\bf \vec x}_{\,h}  \circ {\bf \vec y}_{\,h} } \right)} \,
$$